# Cannot restart thin via remote machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, rubygems, thin

I use Thin to serve the rails application located on a test machine. I'd like to be able to stop/start thin from my local machine but the following does not work:

```
ssh luc@test_machine '/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/thin -v'
```

I got the following error message:

```
/home/luc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find thin (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/luc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /home/luc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1230:in `gem'
from /home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/thin:18:in `<main>'
```

Why does it list only 6 gems when I have scores ?

When I'm connected in ssh onto the test server:

```
which thin
```

gives me the right path:

```
/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/thin  (question updated with correct path)
```

**UPDATE**

I have created a basic test.sh script on the server:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Update path with ruby / gem
export PATH=$PATH:/home/luc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/
thin -v
exit 0
```

I call it from my local machine

```
ssh luc@test_machine '/home/luc/test.sh'
```

But still the same "could not find thin" error.

**UPDATE 2**

This might be linked to the rubies / gemset used when the script is run through ssh. I have added

```
rvm list
rvm gemset list
```

in the test.sh file and the output I have is:

```
rvm rubies

* ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

gemsets for system (found in /home/luc/.rvm/gems/system)
*
```

It seems that the gems I have installed are not there... Don't know to spefify the rubies/gemset version to use through a ssh call though.

Comment: you're not using path that `which thin` gives you. Try changing '/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/thin -v' to '/home/gp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/thin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this using another way. Instead of trying to restart the server from a remote machine, I installed the gem "rerun" (https://github.com/alexch/rerun) so the restart of the thin server is done automatically when some code is changed.

```
rerun -- thin start
```

does the trick really well

Answer (score 0):

Do you use bundler ?

Try doing

```
bundle exec thin -v
```

If this will not work or you don't use bundler, check `$PATH` variable by typing

```
echo PATH
```

if gems are not in path he will not be able to load it, i bet it is something with paths :)
Update them and rock'n'roll

In worst case you will have to generate rvm gem wrappers, for  more info read this

http://beginrescueend.com/integration/god/

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with additional info on the PATH stuff. I'm pretty sure also this is linked to path but cannot figure out yet the reason of this error.

Answer (score 0):

this solutions worked for me ( remote & capistrano ! )

look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10391426/1470996) !

just place:

```
source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # or ~/.rvm/..
rvm use 1.9.3
```

in /etc/init.d/thin

or for capistrano

```
%w[start stop restart].each do |command|
  desc "#{command} thin server"
  task command, roles: :app do
    run "source '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm' && rvm use 1.9.3 && service thin #{command}"
  end
  after "deploy:#{command}", "thin:#{command}"
end
```

if you installed rvm per user change source path to '~/.rvm/scripts/rvm'